# How to select time with fractional second from SQLite and insert in to SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I am inserting data from SQLite to SQL server successfully, but I am unable to insert complete value of Time column "2021-06-23 22:08:22.5584416". I want to insert that complete string in the SQL server but I got only that string ("2021-06-23 22:08:22").
I have tried this query to select data from SQLite:

```
query = "Select * From DataLogger1 where strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f',time) > '"+ Globals.Tags.Last_DateTime_Logger.Value.ToString() + "' Limit 50" ;
```

In this DataLogger1 there is a Time column exists. I want to read complete value as I mentioned above.

Comment: What is the data type of column in SQL Server?

Comment: Can you show more of the code surrounding this query, please. For instance, what type is the variable `time`?

Comment: In SQL server you must potentially use datetime2 instead of datetime.